# jQuery SubMenu opportunity

Tags: jquery, hover, submenu

Ive been workin on this all night to no avail. Typical SubMenu question and Ive read a lot of similar ones on here but cant find a fix.

I have a menu which is a unordered list. I also have a submenu that is the same. I have the menus positioned fine etc. Problem is that when my submenu appears to the side of my regular menu, as SOON as I go from hovering from menu 1 to menu 2, it disappears. Im sure its something simple but could somone take a look?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.nav').hover(function(e) {
    if(!$('.nav2').is(':visible'))
    {
        $('.nav2').fadeIn('slow');
    }
},function(){
    if(!$('.nav2').is(':hover'))
    {
        $('.nav2').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});

$('.nav2').mouseout(function(){
    if(!$('.nav').is(':hover'))
    {
        $('.nav2').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

And my lists are:

```
<div id="col1">

<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.alan.com">About</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.alan.com">New Listings</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Featured Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Town Facts</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav2">
  <li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Bio</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Credentials</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Education</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the submenu into the `li` on the main menu. Something like:

```
<div id="col1">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.alan.com">About</a>
            <ul class="nav2">
                <li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Bio</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Credentials</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Education</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.alan.com">New Listings</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Featured Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Town Facts</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
This should give you some ideas. - [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/LHcUt/)

Comment: Works great but one last question.... when I move to the submenu and then continue off the sub, the sub never disappears unless I move BACK to the MAIN then off of the main menu. What could cause that?

Comment: @RobertMailloux: Edited in a jsfiddle demo to the answer. Hope that helps. (I could not fix the rest of the main menu sliding down in there, though)

Comment: AMAZING!! And your code is so much easier than what I was trying to do. All because of the nested list! THANK YOU!