# Navigation submenu

Tags: jquery, submenu

i wanna ask how to do this submenu using jQuery ?

for example my menu code

```
<div class="menu">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li class="divider"><a href="#">Our Company</a></li>
<li class="divider"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
<li class="divider"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and my submenu code:

```
 <div class="submenu">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="divider-point"><a href="#">ATC</a></li>
    <li class="divider-point"><a href="#">Radars</a></li>
    <li class="divider-point"><a href="#"> Components </a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Finaly result should be like this:

http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/images/60-more-css-techniques/117.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867770/jquery-submenu-opportunity?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695813/how-can-i-get-a-submenu-here?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

```
function subMenu(show) {
    if (show){
      document.getElementById('sub_menu').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('sub_menu').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```